# Appending character to string in Common Lisp

Tags: string, lisp, character, common-lisp

I have a character `ch` that I want to append to a string `str`. I realize you can concatenate strings like such:

```
(setf str (concatenate 'string str (list ch)))
```

But that seems rather inefficient. Is there a faster way to just append a single character?

Answer (score 14):

If the string has a *fill-pointer* and maybe is also *adjustable*.

*Adjustable* = can change its size.

*fill-pointer* = the content size, the length, can be less than the string size.

`VECTOR-PUSH` = add an element at the end and increment the fill-pointer.

`VECTOR-PUSH-EXTEND` = as `VECTOR-PUSH`, additionally resizes the array, if it is too small.

We can make an adjustable string from a normal string:

```
CL-USER 32 > (defun make-adjustable-string (s)
               (make-array (length s)
                           :fill-pointer (length s)
                           :adjustable t
                           :initial-contents s
                           :element-type (array-element-type s)))
MAKE-ADJUSTABLE-STRING
```

`VECTOR-PUSH-EXTEND` then can add characters to the end of the string. Here we add the character `#\!` to the end of the string `"Lisp"`. The result string then is `"Lisp!"`:

```
CL-USER 33 > (let ((s (make-adjustable-string "Lisp")))
               (vector-push-extend #\! s)
               s)
"Lisp!"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to extend a single string multiple times, it is often
quite performant to use with-output-to-string, writing to the stream
it provides.  Be sure to use write or princ etc. (instead of format)
for performance.

Comment: or the obscure alternative, make sure that the FORMAT string can be compiled.